Next.js React-Leaflet bouncing marker using Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing
I am new to the front-end development, I am trying to get bouncing marker in React-leaflet using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.smooth_marker_bouncing/v/1.3.0?activeTab=explore
But I don't have enough documentation to try it, I tried some methods based on the article
https://medium.com/sopra-steria-norge/react-leaflet-a-short-intro-with-animations-4fa8f8c5eb1c
I was able to fly to coordinates but unable to get the bouncing marker. I don't have any errors in console as well as in terminal.
I would really appreciate if someone shared some basic implementation of the plugin in next.js and share the code.
Thanks!

did you use their CSS? Also why you using a third-party library? You can use the main leaflet for that.

As said, I have very little knowledge about frontend, I thought when I use the components it will automatically import, it has many css which one should I load?, also I tried using main leaflet but was not successful, it would be helpful if you share the code, thanks

Finally got it working, for others who are trying to figure out I have given the basic code below
"use client";
import L from "leaflet";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "../../node_modules/leaflet.smooth_marker_bouncing/dist/bundle";

const MMapviewp = () => {
  const bangalore = [12.9716, 77.5946];
  const vellore = [12.7802, 78.7177];
  const chennai = [13.084, 80.27];
  const center = chennai;
  const zoom = 4;
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      const map = L.map(mapRef.current).setView(center, zoom);

      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
      }).addTo(map);

      L.marker(vellore)
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("popup")
        .on("click", function () {
          console.log("Clicked");
          this.bounce(2) // bounce 2 times
            .on("bounceend", function () {
              console.log("bounce end");
            });
        });
      L.marker(chennai).addTo(map).bindPopup("Vanakkam /n Chennai").bounce(); //Bangalore
      L.marker(bangalore).addTo(map).bindPopup("Namma /n Bengaluru").bounce(); //Chennai
      map.flyTo(vellore, 8.5);
      return () => {
        map.remove();
      };
    }
  }, [center, zoom]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={mapRef}
      className="leaflet-container"
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    />
  );
};

export default MMapviewp;

